# generate a list of numbers using information from another list

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like this:

```
100 2
300 3
50 1
500 5
```

and I want to generate a pool of numbers where the occurance of the number that is the first number in the list should occur x times (x is the second number in the list).

This is what I want the output to be:

```
[100, 100, 300, 300, 300, 50, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500]
```

I wrote a function like this:

```
def Pool(pos, count):
    pool = pos*int(count)
    return pool
```

and for each line I appended all the numbers to a variable called bigpool

```
bigpool = []
for line in weightposfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    f = line.split('\t')
    pos = f[0]
    count = int(f[1])
    pool = Pool(pos, count)
    bigpool.append(pool)
```

but this will return a list like this:

```
[100100, 300300300, 50, 500500500500500]
```

How can I seperate the numbers and get the output I want (shown above)?

Comment: Do keep in mind than the Python convention is to only use a leading uppercase for class names. It's just a convention, but `pool` would be the expected name for a function like yours in most settings.

Comment: That output can't have been generated by that code.  Your "pos" is a string, so the output should have looked like `['100100', '300300300', '50', '500500500500500']`.  Please copy and paste code and output you want comment on.

Comment: You´re right, it looked like that. sorry! I´ll copy paste next time.

Comment: @edg: no worries!  It just saves time all around, so it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: exactly :) I´m still just a beginner, so tips are more than welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
def Pool(pos, count):
    return [pos] * count

bigpool = []
for line in weightposfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    f = line.split('\t')
    pos = f[0]
    count = int(f[1])
    pool = Pool(pos, count)
    bigpool += pool
```

I changed two lines. `return [pos] * count` will make array of `pos`.

`bigpool += pool` will append the elements of `pool` to `bigpool`.

Comment: I want to sample from this bigpool x many values 1000 times and tried this:

Comment: randomsample = random.sample(bigpool, x), but dont know how to do it 1000 times?

Comment: I'd only add that `Pool` isn't a very good function name, both because python functions are generally not capitalized, and also because "Pool" has a specific meaning in a threading/multiprocessing context.

Comment: That´s good to know, I didn´t know pool has a specific meaning - and I´ll fix the capitalized function name, thanks!

Comment: Sample the pool 1000 times the same way you'd do anything else 1000 times: with a loop that executes 1000 times performing the operation once each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) and the [`itertools.repeat()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) function.

```
from itertools import repeat, chain
with open("file.dat", "r") as f:
    output = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(int(number), int(count)) for (number, count) in (line.split() for line in f)))
print(output)
```

Which gives us:

```
[100, 100, 300, 300, 300, 50, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500]
```

Now, this is a pretty complicated list comprehension (well, technically a generator comprehension), so let's break it down. We begin by opening the file (using the `with` statement as is a best practice). The first thing we do is take all the lines and split them on white-space, giving us lists of number, count pairs.

```
(line.split() for line in f)
```

We then take those pairs and repeat the number the given number of times:

```
repeat(int(number), int(count)) for (number, count) in ...
```

We now have a generator of repeat generators (essentially a list of lists), so we expand these out into a single list:

```
list(chain.from_iterable(...))
```

If you just follow it through, this is actually a really nice way of doing it in a single line of code. It makes a lot on sense and is actually very readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Pool(pos, count):
    pool = [int(pos) for x in range(int(count))]
    return pool
```

Answer (score 0):

You're so close! Just do:

```
bigpool = []
for line in weightposfile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    f = line.split('\t')
    pos = []
    pos.append(f[0])
    count = int(f[1])
    pool = Pool(pos, count)
    bigpool.extend(pool)
```

Multiply a list by an integer `a` adds `a` times of each element to the list.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
fromfile = "100 2\n300 3\n50 1\n500 5"
result = []
for entry in fromfile.split("\n"):
    num, count = entry.split()
    for i in range(int(count)):
        result.append(num)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation, it works as expected and is a bit simpler:

```
def pool(pos, count):
    return [pos] * int(count)

bigpool = []
for line in weightposfile:
    pos, count = line.strip().split()
    bigpool.extend(pool(pos, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have a variable spacing, this should work to what you need:

```
import re
results = []
pre = re.compile('^(\d+)\s+(\d+)',re.M)

for line in weightposfile.split("\n"):
    matchline = pre.match(line)
    for i in range(int(matchline.group(1))):
        results.append(matchline.group(0))
print results
```